# Capture incoming URL Parameters, then pass to iFrame Src with Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, query-string, window.location

So trying to figure out how to do this with window.location in Javascript. I'm sending users to our site with an appended URL with a Google Analytics code that I need to pass to an iframe src on that page. I'd assume Javascript could do this (note - I cannot use PHP)...

This is what I want to do:

I'd send users to the page with all the campaign data in tact. For example a user would click on this link:
    http://www.xyz.com/index.html?utm_source=Facebook&utm_campaign=Facebook+May&utm_medium=click

They would be directed to that page, that then has this iFrame on it. The code on the store side would need to pick up utm_source, utm_campaign, utm_medium and include these parts in the IFRAME SRC So this bit:

```
<iframe height="960px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="958px" src="http://www.abc.com/minis"></iframe>
```

now becomes:

```
 <iframe height="960px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="958px" src="http://www.abc.com/minis?utm_source=Facebook&utm_campaign=Facebook+May&utm_medium=click"></iframe>
```

Any javascript suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Note - I cannot use PHP.

***UPDATE:
Got this to work!! Yay, but now I need to edit it a bit:***

So say the appended url that was clciked was this:

```
http://abc.com/index.html?apple&orange&peach
```

and I need the iframe src to be this

```
 http://xyz.com/minis?orange&peach
```

I moved a few things around in the script, but is now only grabbing orange and not the other & attribute (peach). please advise if there is a better way to work (without have all the params and then depending on what link comes in, some of the & will be undefined:

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

var loc = window.location.toString(),
params = loc.split('&')[1],
params2 = loc.split('&')[2],
params3 = loc.split('&')[3],
params4 = loc.split('&')[4],
params5 = loc.split('&')[5],
params6 = loc.split('&')[6],
  iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
alert(iframe.src); 
iframe.src = iframe.src + '?' + params + '&' + params2 + '&' + params3 + '&' + params4+ '&' + params5;
alert(iframe.src); 

});
</script>
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.xyz.com/minis"></iframe>

</body>
```

Comment: use jquery to get the parameters then dynamically insert your new iframe with whatever you want. simple

Comment: my iframe html code contains a form within it, how can i pass URL Parameter to iframe form Action ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This little snippet should do, here all you have to do is grab the bit after ? as a string and append it to the iframe source.

```
var loc = window.location.toString(),
    params = loc.split('?')[1],
    iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');

iframe.src = iframe.src + '?' + params;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: so I've put together here but it isn't working properly. I'll admit, Javascript isn't my strong suit. http://jsfiddle.net/GLm5f/

Comment: you got the id wrong, you are missing the I in uppercase like in the JS, it's myIframe, not myiframe - my bad should have just use foo no confusion there.

Comment: hmmm...changed to ID instead of name and changed myIframe, but I still don't see it. Once I come in with the appended code, will it show in the view source? so if I come in on that appended google analytics URL, the view source for the iframe src should have the appended tag?

Comment: it wont work on fiddle, there is no param in the window.location and also you had mootools selected as library on the left panel. http://jsfiddle.net/GLm5f/2/ check the log it grab them ok, try it proper as iframe wont load external content on fiddle.

Comment: I understand it won't work in jfiddle, but I can't get it to work locally when using an appended url (locally).

Comment: Quick suggestion -- put an `alert(iframe.src);` before and after iframe.src is modified so you can see what's happening.

Comment: perfect!!! Thank you. It just wasn't showing up in the view source but the alert is telling me it changes! This is fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: actually, I already have stuff after the questions mark so I need the javascript to pick up after the & and don't stop at the second & sign. So say the appended url that was clciked was this: http:///abc.com/index.html?apple&orange&peach and I need the iframe src to be this http://xyz.com/minis?orange&peach. I moved a few things around in the script, but is now only grabbing orange and not the other & attribute (peach). please advise.

Comment: So this is what I did:
    var loc = window.location.toString(),
params = loc.split('&')[1],
params2 = loc.split('&')[2],
params3 = loc.split('&')[3],
params4 = loc.split('&')[4],
params5 = loc.split('&')[5],
params6 = loc.split('&')[6],
iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
alert(iframe.src); 
iframe.src = iframe.src + '?' + params + '&' + params2 + '&' + params3 + '&' + params4+ '&' + params5;
alert(iframe.src); 

but is there a way to have a if additional & statements, so I don't have to spell out each one?

Comment: You can see my code above in my original post, so it is a little easier to read...

Comment: To start with don't need to use split multiple time, just once at the end of the loc = window.location.... line as it return an array with all the bits you are after. Then you can loop through the array using $.each(loc, function(i, val) {}); Also build an array of the one you don't want var unwanted = ['peach=orange']; and in your each callback you can use the $.inArray() method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) if it's in the unwanted array ignore it, if not use it. Ah yeah forgot have params = '' and then just use += to add to it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `window.location.search`.

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
iframe.src = iframe.src + window.location.search;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Short, sweet, elegant. Loved this!